# Error: expected type-specifier before '...' when compiling code on linux

Tags: c++

So, I have some platform dependent code that is compiling on Linux and Windows using winusb or  libusb.
I use precompiler directives to include the correct header files and also to create the correct interfaces:

```
#include "../path/myusbint.hpp"
#ifdef WIN32 
#include "../path/winusbint.h"
#else
#include "../path/libusbint.h"
#endif
boost::shared_ptr<myusbinerface> usbinterface;

#ifdef WIN32
    usbinterface.reset(new winusbint);
#else
    usbinterface.reset(new libusbint);
#endif
```

On Windows it compiles fine, but on Linux (gcc) I get the error:

```
error: expected type-specifier before `libusbint'
error: expected ')' before `libusbint'
```

Comment: On which line do you get the error? And you do include the header file where `myusbinterface` and `USBInterfaceLibUSB` are defined?

Comment: Did you cut and past that first line? Because it looks like you either have a typo in your code or a typo in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, some code you haven't shown us uses a type called `USBInterfaceLibUSB` at a point where it hasn't been declared. You'd need to show us the actual code that causes the error to be sure.

If that's the correct type name, then make sure that whichever file uses it includes either the header that defines that type, or a forward declaration if you don't need the full definition.

If it's the wrong name then change it to the right name. Perhaps it should be `myusbinerface` to match the code you posted? Or perhaps you spell that correctly (`myusbinterface`) in your real code?

Comment: Thx for pointing it out. i changed the error message accordingly

Comment: So are you including the header that defined `libusbint`? That's the most likely cause of the error.

Comment: I did, I added hwo include the files.

Comment: @tzippy: And can you confirm that the error comes from the code you've posted (the `new libusbint` line), not from the header or somewhere else? And that the header does define `libusbint`? Is that the only error message, or are there some before it?

Comment: It indeed originates (the error) from the `new libusbint` line. and `libusbint` is definetly defined in the header.

Comment: @tzippy: Well, the compiler isn't seeing the definition; either the header doesn't define it correctly, or it's not getting included. You could use `gcc -E` to see the preprocessor output, and check whether that contains the definition. Do your headers contain include guards? Might you have accidentally defined the same guard in more than one header?

Comment: I found it. It couldn't see the definition because the headerfile, inspite of being included was invisible because of a surrounding `#ifdef`. Thanks!